# How can I create a regex to match mm/dd pattern with valid ranges?

Tags: regex, html, date

I am trying to create a date field that only allows users to enter a date as:

```
mm/dd
```

I would also like to add that `mm` can only have a range of `01-12`, and `dd` can only have a range of `01-31`

I've started with this:

```
<input type="tel" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" name="myInput" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" pattern="\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/" maxlength="5" placeholder="MM/DD">
```

Which works for checking `mm/dd`, but I can enter any range of numbers. I need to make sure that `mm` can only be valid month numbers (1-12). Just as `dd` can only be valid day numbers. (1-31)

I am using input masking to make sure that the user automatically gets a "/" symbol and can only enter a max of 5 characters.

This is the objective I am trying to accomplish:

```
Please enter a month (01-12) and a day (01-31)
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: try February, 31st :) The only regex solution would not worth the effort

Comment: That's fine, it's a valid date. Meaning, any month can have 31 days. There are no months with 32 days. Just as there are no years with 13 months.

Comment: Try `^(?:0[1-9]|1[012])\/(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$` if Feb 31st is fine

Comment: Little more refined one: `^(?:(04|06|09|11)|(01|03|05|07|08|10|12)|(02))\/(?(1)(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30)|(?(2)(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])|(0[1-9]|[12][0-9])))$` This will allow upto 30 days for Apr, June, Sep, Nov, 31 days for Jan, Mar, May, Jul, Aug, Oct, Dec and Feb 29 days (regardless of the leap year).

Comment: @Matt.G Thank you so much. I used your first example and is exactly what I needed. If you post as the answer, I'll mark it accepted. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex:

```
^(?:0[1-9]|1[012])\/(?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$
```

Please note that this matches few invalid dates like 02/30, 02/31

Comment: Understood. It is only important in my use case that any year can't have 13 months and any month can't have 32 days. This works great - thank you very much!